# Product url rewrite not working when product import using csv from admin in magento2?

Tags: magento2

Product url rewrite not working when product import using csv from admin in magento2

Comment: it's by default magento bug.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites  It regenerates the product and category urls.

Comment: @SukumarGorai I have imported many products before and also rewrited url.
I am sure that in magento 2.2.3 it's working

i don't know which magento version it's stop functionality
Have any idea about it?

Comment: I had the same issue in Magento 2.2.4(migration) then use the above module and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually error is i am makng **url_key** column blank when importing product.

If you want to rewrited url you have must **url_key** column value in csv file.